# Interleave two 64-bit NEON vectors?

Tags: c, neon, intrinsics

I'm working on a port of SSE2 to NEON. The SSE code performs the following:

```c
int64x2_t a, b, c, d;
...
a = interleave_high64(b, interleave_low64(c, d));
```

And it performs the following in place of `_mm_unpackhi_epi64` and `_mm_unpacklo_epi64`:

```c
static inline int64x2_t interleave_low64(int64x2_t a, int64x2_t b) {
    const int64x2x2_t result = vzip_s64(vget_low_s64(a), vget_low_s64(b));
    return vcombine_s64(result.val[0], result.val[1]);
}
static inline int64x2_t interleave_high64(int64x2_t a, int64x2_t b) {
    const int64x2x2_t result = vzip_s64(vget_high_s64(a), vget_high_s64(b));
    return vcombine_s64(result.val[0], result.val[1]);
}
```

My first, immediate question is, why is `vzip_s64` missing (though `vzip_s32` and `vzip_s16` [are available](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABDCGGF.html)). Or maybe, what should I use in its stead?

I'm guessing there's a bigger pattern at hand, and it might even use `VSTR.2` for an inteleaved store. My second question is, what should I be doing instead of the three or four NEON intrinsics?

Comment: `vzip_s64` would "interleave" two 64-bit elements into a 128-bit vector, which `vcombine_s64` already does perfectly well ;)

Comment: Thanks @Notlikethat - So I'm clear (forgive my ignorance)... I only need `interleave_low64 { return vcombine_s64(vget_low_s64(a), vget_low_s64(b))}`. Is that correct?